# Convert a List<T> to a nested Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, T>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm stuck on a basic problem. I need to convert a flat List to a Nested dictionary of type `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>>`

I've almost done except the fact that I need to group multiple properties, and I used an anonymous type for that. Here is an example :

```
List<ApprovalAction> Gen()
{
    return new List<ApprovalAction>
    {
        new ApprovalAction { Name = "SendMailToApprover", Step="New", ApprovalRequestType = "Homeworking", ParameterName = "to", ParameterValue="Approver" },
        new ApprovalAction { Name = "SendMailToApprover", Step="New", ApprovalRequestType = "Homeworking", ParameterName="subject", ParameterValue = "Aproval Request" },
        new ApprovalAction { Name = "SendMailToApprover", Step="New", ApprovalRequestType = "Homeworking", ParameterName="body", ParameterValue = "I would like an approval request"},
        new ApprovalAction { Name = "SendMailToApprover", Step="New", ApprovalRequestType = "Absence", ParameterName="to" , ParameterValue="Approver" },
        new ApprovalAction { Name = "SendMailToApprover", Step="New", ApprovalRequestType = "Absence", ParameterName="subject", ParameterValue = "Aproval Request" },
        new ApprovalAction { Name = "SendMailToApprover", Step="New", ApprovalRequestType = "Absence", ParameterName="body", ParameterValue = "I would like an approval request"}
    };
}


    var actions = Gen();
    var dico = actions
                .GroupBy(x => x.ApprovalRequestType)
                .ToDictionary(
                    gdc => gdc.Key,
                    gdc => gdc.GroupBy(a => a.Step)
                            .ToDictionary(dd => dd.Key, dd => dd.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Step, x.ApprovalRequestType }, (key, group) => new
                            {
                                Key = key.Name,
                                Result = group.ToDictionary(k => k.ParameterName, v => v.ParameterValue)
                            })));
```

This is the output of Linqpad :

[image]

Do you know by which code I can replace to avoid the IEnumerable ?

Thank you !

Comment: .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Explain what you want to do, not how you though you could do it. Looks like you want to create a hierarchy of something (what?) by  ApprovalRequestType, then what? It's hard to understand what the code does since it doesn't even fit in the question without scrolling. You can do this with some kind of grouping but you'll have to explain what you want to do first

Comment: `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>>`??? How would you get from `List<T>` to that monstrosity?

Comment: Regarding monstrosities, it's a *LOT* easier to work if you create different types for each level. You don't need dictionaries for this. If you think you need them because eg you want to generate Json, you don't. JSON serializers convert object graphs to dictionary notations by themselves

Comment: If I had the choice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<>` comes from the final `GroupBy`. If you know that the innermost group would contain exactly one item, use `Single()`. Otherwise use `First()`:

```
var dico = actions
    .GroupBy(x => x.ApprovalRequestType)
    .ToDictionary(
        gdc => gdc.Key,
        gdc => gdc.GroupBy(a => a.Step)
            .ToDictionary(dd => dd.Key, dd => dd.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Step, x.ApprovalRequestType }, (key, group) => new {
                Key = key.Name,
                Result = group.ToDictionary(k => k.ParameterName, v => v.ParameterValue)
            }).First()
        )
    );
```

Result of the query above looks like this:

[image: LINQPad result]

Comment: Oh perfect, I replace the .First() by a .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Result) to avoid the ø